# Use reflection to get actual return type form Task<List<Dictionary<string,object>>> instead of object

Tags: c#, reflection, generic-list

I am trying to get the actual object that is contained within a list that itself is contained within a task.

e.g. method has the following signature e.g.

```
public async Task<List<Dictionary<string,object>>> GetData()
```

i am currently using something like this:

```
var member = type.GetMembers()[0];
var returntype = member.ReturnType.GetGenericArguments();
var temp = member.ReturnType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
if (temp.GetGenericArguments().Count() > 0)
{
    temp.GetTypeInfo().GetGenericArguments();
    var innerttype = temp.GetGenericArguments()[0].FullName;
}
```

Currently the above code (which is not complete but just an extract from actual code) return system.object as fullname instead of  Dictionary.

Any suggestions to solve this are welcome.

Comment: I ran your code and `innerttype` prints to `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary'2[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Object, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]` - exactly what you want.

Comment: To get the actual type of the object value stored in the dictionary you need to execute `value.GetType()`. As far as I can see you are using reflection to drill down into the return type of the `GetData` method and it clearly states that the dictionary contains values of type `object`. To learn the actual type of each object instance you need to inspect them separately.

Answer (score 0):

If you declare your dictionary to be of type `<string, object>` and and only ever insert objects inside it and not something higher up in the graph, you'll only ever get `object` typed objects out of it.

If you're storing all kinds of things in there and need to get their concrete type so you can interact with them, try to make them all conform to an interface first. Then, put the interface type in there replacing "object." If that doesn't work you can use generics. However, you'll still need to know the type ahead of time in order to be able to interact with it.

If you really have no idea what's in there and want to dig into it dynamically, that's precisely what Reflection was built for. You could also look into the [`dynamic` type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx).